# How to add two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add two variables but they are concatenating with each other instead of adding

```
 var price = 10;
 $("#val").blur(function(){
  var get_val = $(this).val();
  var get_vale = price + get_val ;
  alert("there are " + get_vale + " in your cart");
 });
```

How do I add these variables and not concatenate them?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: It's pure javascript behavior an unrelated to jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the value you are getting from `$("#val")` is a string instead of an `int`.

Use `parseInt`, lookup the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
var price = 10;
$("#val").blur(function(){
  var val = $(this).val(),
      int_val = parseInt(val, 10), //ensure this is an Int
      get_vale = price + int_val;
 alert("there are " + get_vale + " in your cart");
});
```

Specified *radix* is `10`, as written in the documentation:

> Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans

Comment: Remember radix: `parseInt('0x15') == 21`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to concat string and number. Previously, you must to convert string to number. There is some ways to do it:

```
var get_val = +$(this).val();
```

or

```
var get_val = Number($(this).val());
```

or if you want integer

```
var get_val = parseInt($(this).val());
```

otherwise

```
var get_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

to concatenate variables use the "+" sign and use the parseInt function to get the numeric value of the variable in order to properly do math functions

```
var get_val = parseInt($(this).val());
```